# AdMob. Invoke Firebase method getInstance error

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, admob

Пытаюсь встроить в приложение рекламу, следуя оф. [гайду](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=ru),в котором указано, что описанный способ не требует Firebase.

```
    public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    protected AdView adView;
    protected View gameView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        //View gameView = initializeForView(new AdMobTest(), config);

        gameView = initializeForView(new AdMobTest(), config);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);


        // Create and setup the AdMob view
        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        builder.addTestDevice("6BD6DB797D7C2C576A7317E3BBF21B75");

        InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(builder.build());
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        // Hook it all up
        setContentView(layout);

    }
}
```

При этом получаю вот такие сообщения в логах:

```
07-23 00:15:43.302 24810-25044/com.admobtest.test W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
07-23 00:15:43.302 24810-25044/com.admobtest.test W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
07-23 00:15:43.418 24810-24810/com.admobtest.test I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
07-23 00:15:43.464 24810-24810/com.admobtest.test I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-23 00:15:43.464 24810-24810/com.admobtest.test I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
07-23 00:15:43.473 24810-24810/com.admobtest.test W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
07-23 00:15:43.488 24810-24810/com.admobtest.test W/Ads: The interstitial has not loaded.
07-23 00:15:43.567 24810-25018/com.admobtest.test W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
07-23 00:15:44.041 24810-24939/com.admobtest.test W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
07-23 00:15:44.045 24810-24810/com.admobtest.test W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Использую libgdx. Тестирую на физическом устройстве.

P.S. Решением стало добавление в build.gradle:

```
android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: build.gradle и соответствующие файлы приложите. Смотрим есть ли firebase sdk

Comment: @SergeMarkov Действительно, дело было в неподключенной firebase sdk. Меня сбило утверждение в мануале того, что для данного способа не нужен firebase. Спасибо за помощь.